# package with that name and diffrent signature already installed in my new system

Tags: android

I bought a new system in last month.
when I want to update my apps that made in old system. but this apps dont update in my phone & show this error: package with that name and diffrent signature already installed in my new system
I dont set a private key for my apps & they were publish in android market
how can I update this apps?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and re-install the application?

Comment: no I dont like uninstall my app.

Comment: What is your new system? maybe I don't understand your question clearly

Comment: I wrote my apps with my computer but now I write with my laptop

Comment: And what is the problem to uninstall and re-install them?

Comment: I use database & if I uninstall it.the database will be removed

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: all of my user dont have rooted device me too. dont have rooted devicde

Comment: Where the DB located? Why you can't backup him?

Comment: I assume the error is when your developing, now on your laptop and you tell the IDE to run your app on your device it won't let you. If that is the case, then you have no option but to uninstall the app and then tell the IDE to relaunch your app on your device.